# ¿Como se realiza un trigger que sume una fila y que esta la asigne en una columna?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, trigger

Bueno el caso es que quiero realizar una suma de una fila y que esta se guarde en un campo aquí de como llevo la tabla: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el caso es que al introducir :

```
UPDATE enero
            SET  totalgastos= enero.alimentacion+enero.transporte+enero.servicios+enero.otros
```

me realiza una suma, como podemos ver :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bueno el caso es que al cambiar un valor de cualquier campo (alimentacion,transporte,servicios,otros) este segura teniendo el mismo valor por el cual tendría que volver a introducir el :

```
UPDATE enero
                SET  totalgastos= enero.alimentacion+enero.transporte+enero.servicios+enero.otros
```

así que me vi la tarea de crear un trigger para que realizara la suma de forma automática, cuando se cambiara un valor de la tabla:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarenero` BEFORE UPDATE ON `enero` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE enero SET totalgastos= enero.alimentacion+enero.transporte+enero.servicios+enero.otros
```

El problema esta en que al intentar cambiar algún valor no me deja y me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no se que estoy haciendo mal :/.

PD: Gracias por la atención :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no puedes modificar por medio de un `trigger` la tabla que invocó dicho evento. En este caso particular, antes de usar un trigger te conviene más el uso de un [generated field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), el cual trabaja como una fórmula que se actualiza según actualices los campos asociados.
En tu caso, en la estructura de la tabla modifica:

```
`totalGastos` DOUBLE AS (ingreso + alimentacion + ... + otros)
```

Ahora, no viene a tu pregunta, pero es recomendable por normalización usar una tabla de gastos y una de sumarizado/totales, en ese caso sí podrías usar un trigger.